# filter graphviz dot file

Tags: graphviz, dot, ninja, meson-build

I have a project meson based, and I am able to generate using ninja a dot file

```
ninja -t graph myExecutable | dot -Tpng -ograph.png
```

Now I would like to filter the dot file to exclude all the obj files in order to have only the library and the executable.
Is it possible to filter the generated dot file?

this is an example of the  output of
ninja -t graph myExecutable
that i need to filter

```
digraph ninja {
rankdir="LR"
node [fontsize=10, shape=box, height=0.25]
edge [fontsize=10]
"0x55f191f3ea60" [label="myexec"]
"0x55f191f3e9f0" [label="c_LINKER", shape=ellipse]
"0x55f191f3e9f0" -> "0x55f191f3ea60"
"0x55f191f3e6a0" -> "0x55f191f3e9f0" [arrowhead=none]
"0x55f191f3d5d0" -> "0x55f191f3e9f0" [arrowhead=none]
"0x55f191f3e6a0" [label="myexec.p/src_myexec.c.o"]
"0x55f191f3e730" -> "0x55f191f3e6a0" [label=" c_COMPILER"]
"0x55f191f3e730" [label="../src/myexec.c"]
"0x55f191f3d5d0" [label="subprojects/mylib/libmylib.so.p/libmylib.so.symbols"]
"0x55f191f3d6d0" -> "0x55f191f3d5d0" [label=" SHSYM"]
"0x55f191f3d6d0" [label="subprojects/mylib/libmylib.so"]
"0x55f191f3d220" -> "0x55f191f3d6d0" [label=" c_LINKER"]
"0x55f191f3d220" [label="subprojects/mylib/libmylib.so.p/src_library.c.o"]
"0x55f191f3d320" -> "0x55f191f3d220" [label=" c_COMPILER"]
"0x55f191f3d320" [label="../subprojects/mylib/src/library.c"]
}
~
```

I would like to remove all *.c *.o reference

Comment: It is possible to filter a generated dot file, but it depends on the contents.  Please include the output from `ninja -t graph myExecutable >myfile.gv`

Comment: @sroush
an example  otput  ninja -t graph myExecutable has been pasted to the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **gvpr** program (part of the Graphviz system - https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) that will delete all nodes with labels that end in **.o** or **.c**.
It takes your **ninja** output and produces a filtered input suitable as input to **dot**.
Note:

- **gvpr** uses **ksh** (**bash?**) pattern matching syntax
- once a node is deleted, any edges to/from that node are automatically deleted also.  This may not me exactly what you want

```
gvpr -c 'N{if($.label=="@(*.[co])")delete($G,$);}' ninja.gv |dot -Tpng >ninja.png
```

or

```
ninja -t graph myExecutable | gvpr -c 'N{if($.label=="@(*.[co])")delete($G,$);}' |dot -Tpng >ninja.png
```

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]